# .NET Core 3.1 JsonSerializer fails to deserialize simple JSON

Tags: c#, json, .net-core, system.text.json

Trying to deserialize a simple JSON string to a Rules object in .NET Core 3.1

```
using System.Text.Json;

namespace Whatever
{
  public class Rules
  {
    public SyncResponse SyncResponse;

    public Rules Load() 
    {
      var text = File.ReadAllText("/path/to/json.txt");
      var options = new JsonSerializerOptions 
      { 
        PropertyNameCaseInsensitive = true, 
        ReadCommentHandling = JsonCommentHandling.Skip 
      };

      var result = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<Rules>(text, options);
      return result;
    }
  }

  public class SyncResponse
  {
    public string Status;
  }
}
```

The content of the JSON file looks as follows

```
/* Some comment here */
{"SyncResponse":{"status":"success"}}
```

However; when I call Rules.Load(), it returns an instance of Rules, but SyncResponse is null. Can anyone point out what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Try making your fields properties (e.g. `public string Status { get; set; }`

Comment: Thanks @MartinCostello, that was the solution! Mind to write that as an answer; so that I can upvote it?

Comment: Currently `System.Text.Json` [ignores a fields](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/system-text-json-how-to#serialization-behavior), this is a main point here